# Selecting elements from a list maximizing a function

Tags: r, stock, portfolio

I was trying to create some R code from my thesis. Contextualizing my situation I've divided the 505 time series' components of S&P500 with dtw algorithm in 10 clusters. Initially I've created 100 portfolios randomly taking 1 stock for each cluster diversifying the portfolios. Then I've created a code with which I can assign each portfolio' stock a weight with Genetic Algorithm maximizing the Sharpe Ratio.

I was wondering if is there a solution for taking stocks for each cluster maximizing the sharpe ratio to obtain an optimized solution.

Comment: IF you can write the function you want to optimize, you could do so with `optim` or `optimize` functions

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I've already created a function that maximize the Sharpe Ratio to assign each stock a weight. But the portfolio on wich i use this optimization are randomly created from different clusters. I was wondering if there is a way to select stock from different clusters that maximize the sharpe ratio. R would calculate any possible combination, weight each stock, calculate the sharpe and than find the best optimized portfolio. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method from the local-search family, such as Stochastic Local Search or Simulated Annealing.  For R examples, see [Asset selection with Local Search](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMOF/vignettes/LSselect.pdf) or the more recent [Optimization Heuristics: A Tutorial](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/Papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756). (Disclosure: I am the maintainer of the [`NMOF` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF), which is used in the examples.)